# How to delete arbitrary numbers of columns from a matrix in mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation

Say I have a matrix of random integers, which is given by

```
A=RandomInteger[25, {9, 11}]
```

How can specific columns of this matrix (say 4th and 7th columns) be deleted?

**EDIT**

It is really surprising that some people have found this question duplicate. I have asked for two specific columns, but it can be extended to any numbers of columns. Say I have a matrix of (985 x 1123), and I want to delete column no. 18, 37, 54, 85, 305, 564 and 1029 from the original matrix to get a new matrix of size (985 x 1116).

Comment: `Delete[Transpose@A, {{4}, {7}}] // Transpose`

Comment: `mA[[All, Complement[Range[11], {4, 7}]]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am confused by the complexity of many of these responses.  The single command

`Drop[A, None, {4,7,3}]`

is sufficient to remove columns $4$ and $7$, in steps of $3$ (so as not to remove columms $5$ and $6$).  If you wanted to remove more than two columns that are not separated by an equal number of columns, then you would need to use `Drop` more than once, starting from the rightmost column to be removed; e.g., to remove columns $1$, $3$, and $9$, you could just do

`Drop[Drop[A, None, {9}], None, {1,3,2}]`

or equivalently,

`Drop[Drop[A, None, {3,9,6}], None, {1}]`

If you had an arbitrary sorted list of column indices to remove, which we might call `c`, then `Fold[]` is trivially applied:

`Fold[Drop[#1, None, {#2}]&, A, Reverse[c]]`

Comment: I considered `Drop`, but because you cannot give give it an arbitrary list of column indices, I decided that `Part` is more suited for the job. Especially because repeated calls to `Drop` is going to be slow for large matrices.

Answer (score 11):

I learned this method long time ago from Mr Wizard answer, it works well. But there are many other ways

```
a = RandomInteger[25, {9, 11}];
a // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ReplacePart[a, {{_, 4}, {_, 7}} :> Sequence[]];
MatrixForm[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Some variations on this theme. Mr.Wizard's `(## &[])` can be substituted for `Sequence[]`. In recent versions of Mathematica, substituting `Nothing`  works too.

Comment: Again, my obligatory warning: This method unpacks arrays.

Answer (score 9):

The fasted way to do this is to use `Part` and construct the indices you need to take using `Complement`:

```
dropColumns[mat_?MatrixQ, columns : {__Integer}] := With[{
   columnsToTake = Complement[
     Range[Dimensions[mat][[2]]],
     columns
   ]
 },
    mat[[All, columnsToTake]]
];
a = RandomInteger[25, {9, 11}];
a // MatrixForm
dropColumns[a, {2, 5}] // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 5):

```
A = RandomInteger[25, {9, 11}]; 
A // MatrixForm
DeleteCol[Matrix_, indexlist_] := 
  Block[{internalMatrix = Matrix, i, k = 0, 
    internallist = SortBy[indexlist, Smaller]},
   For[i = 1, i <= Length[internallist], i++, 
    internalMatrix = 
     Delete[Transpose[internalMatrix], internallist[[i]] - k];
    internalMatrix = Transpose[internalMatrix];
    k++;
    ];
   internalMatrix
   ];
DeleteCol[A, {4, 7}];
% // MatrixForm
DeleteCol[A, {7, 4}];
% // MatrixForm
```

Comment: How can you delete two or more columns?

Comment: @Okkes Dulgerci now it's possible to delete two or more columns.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way to do it. I assume that columns you want delete is ordered. i.e. `{4,7}` will work but `{7,4}` won't.

```
 SeedRandom@2;
    A = RandomInteger[25, {9, 11}];
    MatrixForm@A
```

> $A=\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  23 & 3 & 18 & 11 & 10 & 17 & 8 & 3 & 8 & 0 & 19 \\
>  9 & 23 & 25 & 24 & 14 & 4 & 3 & 4 & 12 & 12 & 8 \\
>  8 & 18 & 6 & 3 & 1 & 14 & 21 & 4 & 14 & 10 & 20 \\
>  22 & 8 & 10 & 20 & 19 & 1 & 9 & 12 & 0 & 19 & 11 \\
>  25 & 10 & 8 & 7 & 18 & 7 & 9 & 23 & 1 & 6 & 15 \\
>  12 & 1 & 0 & 14 & 19 & 12 & 2 & 5 & 3 & 7 & 5 \\
>  23 & 24 & 1 & 14 & 3 & 2 & 22 & 16 & 21 & 4 & 11 \\
>  4 & 2 & 3 & 20 & 24 & 8 & 10 & 3 & 6 & 12 & 19 \\
>  20 & 24 & 6 & 1 & 13 & 10 & 8 & 21 & 5 & 6 & 21 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
deleteColumns[mat_?MatrixQ, col_] := 
 With[{column = col - Range[0, Length@col - 1]}, 
  Fold[Delete[#, #2] &, Transpose@A, column] // Transpose]
deleteColumns[A, {4, 7, 10}] // MatrixForm
```

> $A=\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  23 & 3 & 18 & 10 & 17 & 3 & 8 & 19 \\
>  9 & 23 & 25 & 14 & 4 & 4 & 12 & 8 \\
>  8 & 18 & 6 & 1 & 14 & 4 & 14 & 20 \\
>  22 & 8 & 10 & 19 & 1 & 12 & 0 & 11 \\
>  25 & 10 & 8 & 18 & 7 & 23 & 1 & 15 \\
>  12 & 1 & 0 & 19 & 12 & 5 & 3 & 5 \\
>  23 & 24 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 16 & 21 & 11 \\
>  4 & 2 & 3 & 24 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 19 \\
>  20 & 24 & 6 & 13 & 10 & 21 & 5 & 21 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 3):

```
MapThread[Delete, {A, ConstantArray[{{4}, {7}}, Length[A]]}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a combination of [`Fold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) and [`Drop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Drop.html):

```
ClearAll[dropCols1]
dropCols1 = Fold[Drop[#, None, #2] &, #, List /@ Reverse @ Sort[#2]] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
m = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {9, 9}];

dropCols1[m, {4, 7}] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\small\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,5} & a_{1,6} & a_{1,8} & a_{1,9} \\
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,5} & a_{2,6} & a_{2,8} & a_{2,9} \\
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,5} & a_{3,6} & a_{3,8} & a_{3,9} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,5} & a_{4,6} & a_{4,8} & a_{4,9} \\
>  a_{5,1} & a_{5,2} & a_{5,3} & a_{5,5} & a_{5,6} & a_{5,8} & a_{5,9} \\
>  a_{6,1} & a_{6,2} & a_{6,3} & a_{6,5} & a_{6,6} & a_{6,8} & a_{6,9} \\
>  a_{7,1} & a_{7,2} & a_{7,3} & a_{7,5} & a_{7,6} & a_{7,8} & a_{7,9} \\
>  a_{8,1} & a_{8,2} & a_{8,3} & a_{8,5} & a_{8,6} & a_{8,8} & a_{8,9} \\
>  a_{9,1} & a_{9,2} & a_{9,3} & a_{9,5} & a_{9,6} & a_{9,8} & a_{9,9} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
dropCols1[m, {4, 7, 1}] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\small\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,5} & a_{1,6} & a_{1,8} & a_{1,9} \\
>  a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,5} & a_{2,6} & a_{2,8} & a_{2,9} \\
>  a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,5} & a_{3,6} & a_{3,8} & a_{3,9} \\
>  a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,5} & a_{4,6} & a_{4,8} & a_{4,9} \\
>  a_{5,2} & a_{5,3} & a_{5,5} & a_{5,6} & a_{5,8} & a_{5,9} \\
>  a_{6,2} & a_{6,3} & a_{6,5} & a_{6,6} & a_{6,8} & a_{6,9} \\
>  a_{7,2} & a_{7,3} & a_{7,5} & a_{7,6} & a_{7,8} & a_{7,9} \\
>  a_{8,2} & a_{8,3} & a_{8,5} & a_{8,6} & a_{8,8} & a_{8,9} \\
>  a_{9,2} & a_{9,3} & a_{9,5} & a_{9,6} & a_{9,8} & a_{9,9} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Alternatively, (1) assign `##&[]` (or `Nothing` in versions 10+) to the desired columns (`dropCols2`) or (2) use a combination of `MapAt` and  `##&[]&` (`dropCols3`):

```
ClearAll[dropCols2, dropCols3]
dropCols2 = Module[{a = #}, a[[All, #2]] = ## &[]; a] &;
dropCols3 = MapAt[## &[] &, #, {{All, #2}}] &;

Equal @@ (#[m, {4, 7}] & /@ {dropCols1, dropCols2, dropCols3})
```

> True

```
Equal @@ (#[m, {4, 7, 1}] & /@ {dropCols1, dropCols2, dropCols3})
```

> True