# How I delete one row and one column of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I think the title says it all. I am looking for a function f[A_matrix, r_Integer, c_Integer] that will return the matrix A with the row r and column c deleted. I know how to delete rows but how about columns?

Thanks, I appreciate

Comment: I tried using the Delete function, eg Delete[A,{2}] deletes the second row

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to remove matrix columns?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17002/correct-way-to-remove-matrix-columns) Also: [How to delete arbitrary numbers of columns from a matrix in mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181338/how-to-delete-arbitrary-numbers-of-columns-from-a-matrix-in-mathematica)

Answer (score 6):

You are after [`Drop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Drop.html)

[image]

Data example

```
MatrixForm[
    matrx=Outer[Row@*List, CharacterRange["A", "E"], Range[5]]
]
```

[image]

Now you can do `Drop[matrix, {row},{column}]`

```
MatrixForm[
     Drop[matrx, {3},{2}]
]
```

[image]

If you want to define your function

```
f[a_List?MatrixQ, row_Integer, column_Integer] := Drop[a, {row},{column}]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
(mat = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}}) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
del[mat_?MatrixQ, col_Integer?(Positive), row_Integer?(Positive)] := 
 Module[{m = mat},
  m[[All, col]] = Sequence[];
  m[[row]] = Sequence[];
  m
  ];
```

Now

```
del[mat, 1, 1] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
del[mat, 2, 2] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You can also assign to `Nothing` instead of `Sequence[]`

Comment: @GustavoDelfino, yes, that works also.

Comment: Great guys, I didn't know about this "All" thing, thank you!