# Strange errors of exceeding RecursionLimit in a function with two arguments, one set delayed and one fixed

Tags: functions, matrix, recursion

## INTRODUCTION

Hi. I feel a bit embarrased asking this question as the answer may be staring me in the face and there are at least two other stackexchange articles related to it.

## MINIMAL WORKING EXAMPLE

In the minimal working example below I do the following:

- I define a matrix familhy a[n] where n is the dimension of the matrix;
- I define a matrix function DropM[M,r,c] which takes a matrix of size n and returns a matrix of size n-1 with row r and column c of the original matrix deleted (So it is good for studying minors in laplace expansions);
- I then define a doubly indexed family of matrices R[m,n_] where
  -- the first argument simply indexes the collection of matrix families and
  -- the second argument (set delayed) will be the size.
  -- R[1,n_]:=a[n] the original matrix family.
  -- Then R[2,n_] and R[3,n_] come from R[1,n_] and R[2,n_] by deleting "fixed" rows and columns.

## PREVIOUS STACK EXCHANGE ARTICLES

I know from previous stackexchange articles that it is dangerous to define recursively with extra parameters. One article suggests making the parameters arguments and another article suggests using global variables. I can't do either here because in the actual project i is a counter controlling a loop(and varies). So I thought I would get around this by defining associations (without set delayed) so that no parameters appear in my function definition. Only the 2nd argument in R[m,n_] is set delayed. The first is fixed (So I am not sure what I am doing wrong).

## THE PROBLEM

The code below runs fine. If I now print e.g. R[2,10] I get an error of "Exceeding the recursion limit". But if I print R[1,11],R[2,10] I get no such error. R[2,10] comes from R[1,11] by dropping a specified row and column. But why do I have to print it to avoid an error (perhaps the combination of set and non set "stores" the computed value). But R[1,n] = a[n] which is well defined for any n and there is no real recursion.

As an example of what is bothering me. Using R[1,11] I can then compute R[2,10] by dropping a row and column. Using R[2,10] I can then compute R[3,9] by dropping a row and column. But I dont see why I have to print (or store) these values to avoid 1000 recursions. The first argument is fixed.

The reason I need R[m,n_] is I want a collection of matrix families and I dont know beforehand how many I will need.

## CONCLUDING REMARKS

Help, explanations (and encouragement) would be greatly appreciated.

## MWE

````
a[n_] := Table[    
   If[i == j + 1 || j == i + 1, -1,      
   If[i == 1 && j == 1  || i == n && j == n, 1,     
    If[i == j && 2  <= i <=  n - 1, 2, 0]]],        
   {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];  

 DropM[M1_, r1_, c1_] :=   
  Module[{M, r, c, b}, M = M1; r = r1; c = c1;  
    b = Delete[M, r]; 
   Return[Transpose[Delete[Transpose[b], c]]]];    

Clear[R, P, Q];   
ParentCount = 1    
R[ParentCount, n_] := R[ParentCount, n] = a[n];   
Print[R["Position #1", ParentCount, 4]];    

ChildCount = 2; ParentCount = 1; i = 2;
P = Association[ChildCount -> ParentCount];   
Q =  Association[ChildCount -> i];  
 
R[ChildCount, n_] :=   
  R[ChildCount, n] =   
   DropM[R[P[[Key[ChildCount]]], n + 1], 1, Q[[Key[ChildCount]]] ];  

Print["Position #2", R[ChildCount, 4]];  < 

ChildCount++; ParentCount++; i--;  <  
 AssociateTo[P, ChildCount -> ParentCount];    
AssociateTo[Q, ChildCount -> i];   

 R[ChildCount, n_] :=   
  R[ChildCount, n] =    
   DropM[R[P[[Key[ChildCount]]], n + 1], 1, Q[[Key[ChildCount]]] ];  

Print["Position #3", R[ChildCount, 3]]; 
```
````

Answer (score 2):

Your style of code is very convoluted and procedural-like, which is not the common and best way to program in Mathematica.

Here are a few tips on how to write a more Mathematica-like code:

1. Generally, try to avoid capitalization of your symbols (functions etc.), because they may interfere with system symbols.
2. No need to reassign local symbols (`M = M1; r = r1; c = c1` ...).
3. There is a [simpler way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/280496/75628) to remove a row and a column from a matrix.
4. No need to wrap the result in `Return` inside your `Module`.
5. No need to use `Key` for accessing values inside `Association`; instead of `Q[[Key[ChildCount]]]`, use `Q[ChildCount]`.
6. There are more elegant ways to create specially structured matrices like yours by using [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html).

Here is a simpler code. I am not sure it is completely correct, because your description is not very clear; please check it yourself. Leave a comment, and I can try to fix the code according to your feedback :)

```
Clear["Global`*"];

a[n_] := Normal[SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1, {n, n} -> 1, Band[{1, 1}] -> 2, 
   Band[{2, 1}] -> -1, Band[{1, 2}] -> -1}, {n, n}]]

R[1, n_] := R[1, n] = a[n]
R[2, n_] := R[2, n] = Drop[R[1, 1 + n], {1}, {2}]
R[3, n_] := R[3, n] = Drop[R[2, 1 + n], {1}, {1}]
```

Comment: Consider the following code equivalent  in definition to the code  you supplied above (and using the simpler syntax)